# Why don’t separators show in the flyout when using a ShellSection in Xamarin.Forms Shell?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, flyout

In my Xamarin.Forms Shell application, I define the flyout items in the `AppShell.xaml.cs` file and not in the `AppShell.xaml` one since I need to define them programmatically. [Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/180149/xamarin-forms-shell-separator-between-flyout-items), I read I can use the `FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems` value to get separators. So, I don’t understand why Xamarin doesn’t show separators when I use the `ShellSection` elements and set their `FlyoutDisplayOptions` as `FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems`. The code through which I define the flyout items is the following:

```
var nli = new FlyoutItem   { FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems };
var nc  = new ShellSection { FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems };

foreach (var kind in kinds) { // "kinds" is retrieved from a service
   var csc = new ShellContent { /* ... */ };
   nc.Items.Add(csc);
}

nli.Items.Add(nc);
ShellItems.Items.Add(nli);
```

[image]

The red area is the one populated by the `foreach` statement. The `FlyoutItem` and `ShellSection` parents have the `FlyoutDisplayOptions` correctly set, but the separators are not shown between the `ShellContent` elements. Why?

Comment: Hi, how about using Xaml, It will show?

Answer (score 9):

To add a separator between FlyoutItems or MenuItems, you can add a MenuItem with a DataTemplate as below:

```
<MenuItem>
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="LightGray"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

You can perhaps convert this into code-behind.
Here is how it looks:

[image: FlyoutMenu with Separators]

Comment: You need to add `IsEnabled="False"` to `<MenuItem ...`, otherwise in Windows is clickable

Answer (score 0):

It should be a default phenomenon in shell,  there is no separators between the items in FlyoutItem.

You could have a look at the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout):

[image]